# Error message "Exception: cannot find the correct atom type" when executing pandas to_hdf

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

I want to save the dataframe df to the .h5 file MainDataFile.h5 :

```
df.to_hdf ("c:/Temp/MainDataFile.h5", "MainData", mode = "w", format = "table", data_columns=['_FirstDayOfPeriod','Category','ChannelId'])
```

and get the following error :

> *** Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> > [dtype->object,items->Index(['Libellé_Article', 'Libellé_segment'], dtype='object')]

Now if I drop the column 'Libellé_Article' from df (which is a string column), I don't get the error message anymore.

What could be wrong with this column ? I suspect a special, forbidden, character in it, but unable to find which so far.

**UPDATE 1**

Following Jeff's comment I have tried to encode the column 'Libellé_Article' :

```
df['Libellé_Article'] = df['Libellé_Article'].str.encode('utf-8')
```

The column now appears like this :

```
df['Libellé_Article']
0                                               b'PAPETERIE'
2                                    b'NR CONTRIBUTION DEEE'
4                                         b'NON UTILISE 103'
7                         b"L'ENFANT SOUS TERREUR/MILLER A."
10                 b'ENERGIE VITALE ET AUTOGUERISON/CHIA M.'
12         b'ENERGIE COSMIQUE CETTE PUISSANCE QUI EST EN ...
13         b'ENERGIE COSMIQUE CETTE PUISSANCE QUI EST EN ...
18                     b"COMMENT ATTIRER L'ARGENT/MURPHY J."
19                     b"COMMENT ATTIRER L'ARGENT/MURPHY J."
```

and when I execute the command to_hdf, I get :

> *** TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [Libellé_Article] because
>   its data contents are [mixed] object dtype

Comment: Is it possible that the conversion is complaining about unicode? Did you try to use [u'Libellé_Article', u'Libellé_segment'] ? I know that this is python 3, but nonetheless...

Comment: I've just tried it, but the result is unfortunately the same

Answer (score 1):

This will work in py2. For py3, this should work w/o the encoding step.
This is actually a 'mixed' column as it includes strings and unicode.

```
In [24]: from pandas.compat import u

In [25]: df = DataFrame({'unicode':[u('\u03c3')] * 5 + list('abc') })

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
  unicode
0       ?
1       ?
2       ?
3       ?
4       ?
5       a
6       b
7       c

In [27]: df['unicode'] = df.unicode.str.encode('utf-8')

In [28]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',data_columns=['unicode'],format='table')

In [29]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df')
Out[29]: 
  unicode
0       ?
1       ?
2       ?
3       ?
4       ?
5       a
6       b
7       c
```